# How to check the surrounding cells of a specific cell in terms of a specific values in a rectangular array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I used the following method to check the cells around a specific cell in terms of a given indexes (row & column) if it zeros or not, see this array:

[image]

The cell that I need to check the surroundings of zeros (horizontally, Vertically or diagonally) could be at the first row, last row, first column, last column or in between i.e. it could be any cell in the rectangular array depending to the "rowIndex" and "colIndex" which are passed to the method.

```
static Boolean TestZero(int[,] array,int colIndex, int rowIndex)
{                 
    /*Check Corners*/
    //First Corner
    if ((rowIndex == 0) && (colIndex == 0)) 
    {

        if (array[1, 0] == 1 || array[0, 1] == 1 || array[1, 1] == 1) return false;


    }

    //Second Corner
    if ((rowIndex == 0) && colIndex >= array.GetUpperBound(0))
    {

        if (array[array.GetUpperBound(0) - 1, 0] == 1 || array[array.GetUpperBound(0),1] == 1 || array[array.GetUpperBound(0)-1,1 ] == 1) return false;


    }

    //Third Corner
    if ((rowIndex >= array.GetUpperBound(1)) && (colIndex == 0))
    {

        if (array[0, array.GetUpperBound(1) - 1] == 1 || array[1, array.GetUpperBound(1)] == 1 || array[1, array.GetUpperBound(1)-1] == 1) return false;


    }

    //Fourth Corner
    if ((rowIndex >= array.GetUpperBound(1)) && (colIndex >= array.GetUpperBound(0)))
    {

        if (array[array.GetUpperBound(0), array.GetUpperBound(1) - 1] == 1 || array[array.GetUpperBound(0) - 1, array.GetUpperBound(1) - 1] == 1 || array[array.GetUpperBound(0) -1, array.GetUpperBound(1)] == 1) return false;


    }

    /* Check Boundries But Not Corners */
    //First Row 
    if ((rowIndex == 0) && (colIndex != array.GetUpperBound(0)) && (colIndex != 0))
    {

        for (int i = rowIndex; i <= rowIndex + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = colIndex - 1; j <= colIndex + 1; j++)
            {
                if ((i != rowIndex) && (j != colIndex))
                {
                    if (array[j,i] == 1) return false;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    //Last Row 
    if ((rowIndex >= array.GetUpperBound(1)) && (colIndex != array.GetUpperBound(0)) && (colIndex != 0))
    {

        for (int i = rowIndex; i <= rowIndex - 1; i--)
        {
            for (int j = colIndex - 1; j <= colIndex + 1; j++)
            {
                if ((i != rowIndex) && (j != colIndex))
                {
                    if (array[j,i] == 1) return false;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    //First & Last Columns 
    if ((rowIndex != array.GetUpperBound(1)) && ((rowIndex != 0)))
    {  
        //First column
       if(colIndex==0) 
       {
        for (int i = rowIndex-1; i <= rowIndex + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = colIndex; j <= colIndex + 1; j++)
            {
                if ((i != rowIndex) && (j != colIndex))
                {
                    if (array[j,i] == 1) return false;
                }
            }
        }

       }

        //Last Column
       if (colIndex == array.GetUpperBound(0)) 
       {
           for (int i = rowIndex -1; i <= rowIndex + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = colIndex; j <= colIndex - 1; j--)
            {
                if ((i != rowIndex) && (j != colIndex))
                {
                    if (array[j,i] == 1) return false;
                }
            }
        }

       }

    }

    /* In Between i.e. Not the Array Boundries */
    if(colIndex!=0 && colIndex != array.GetUpperBound(0) && rowIndex !=0 && rowIndex != array.GetUpperBound(1)) {

        for (int i = rowIndex - 1; i <= rowIndex + 1; i++)
           {
             for (int j = colIndex - 1; j <= colIndex + 1; j++)
               {
                if ((i != rowIndex) && (j != colIndex))
                  {
                  if (array[j,i] == 1) return false;
                  }
               }
           }

     } // end if statment
    return true;
 }
```

I got some wrong result and I tried to figure out the problem, but I could not!.

**Results:**

1- Rectangular arrays (chromosomes in a genetic algorithm population):

[image]

2- The indexes of the cells that we need to check its surroundings:

> |(2,3)||(2,3)||(0,1)||(1,3)||(0,3)||(1,3)|

3- Arrays that contains zero in at least one of the surrounding cells of each of the intended cells:

> Chromosome 0 : True  Chromosome 1 : True  Chromosome 2 : False 
>   Chromosome 3 : True  Chromosome 4 : False  Chromosome 5 : True

Any help to figure out why I got some wrong results!!.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in the debugger? This is already a bit too complex to analyse "by the eye" unless you're very careful. Generalising and simplifying the logic would help (e.g. make a method like `GetSafe` that does the bounds checking, so that you can safely do `GetSafe(-1, 1)` instead of doing yet another explicit if check). It also allows you to make a simple array of the relative positions to check and loop through that, rather than doing `if (GetSafe(...) && GetSafe(...) && GetSafe(...) && ...)` or whatever.

Comment: @Kushina, Is this an ACM question? If not (or if you don't care about performance), use try-catch to deal with the boundary cases, and make your code easier to debug. (similar idea with @Luaan)

Comment: @Kushina, Okay, have a look of my answer, I'm going to test more cases now. But please notice that is rely on Exception mechanism, which means BAD performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, your method checks if a cell is surrounded by cells filled with `1`s and returns `false` if it is. Your code is too complicated for it because you try to look at everything as a different case instead of generilizing it making it very difficult to debug. The following method is an example of a better way to implement the check:

```
    bool TestZero(int[,] mat, int row, int col)
    {
        int ones = 0, cells = 0;//define counters

        //define bounderies
        int rowLen = Math.Min(row + 1, mat.GetLength(0) - 1),
            colLen = Math.Min(col + 1, mat.GetLength(1) - 1),
            rowIdx = Math.Max(0, row - 1),
            colIdx = Math.Max(0, col - 1);
        for (int i = rowIdx; i <= rowLen; i++)
        {
            for (int j = colIdx; j <= colLen; j++)
            {
                //if it is our given index, continue
                if (i == row && j == col)
                    continue;
                ++cells;//increment cells counter
                if (mat[i, j] == 1)//if the value of the cell is 1
                    ++ones;//increment the ones counter
            }
        }

        return ones < cells;//if there are less cells with '1' then 
                            //surrounding cells, return true.
    }
```

What we do here is:

create two counters: one counts the amount of cells surrounding the given cell and another counts how many ones surround it.

We save the bounderies of the loops in variables:

- rowLen: the last row index to visit. It is the smaller value between the row index of the given cell + 1 and the last row index in the matrix.
- rowIdx: the starting row index to check in the loop. The bigger value between the row index of the given cell - 1 and the first row index in the matrix (0).
- colLen: same as rowLen just for the columns.
- colIdx: same as rowIdx just for columns.

Then we iterate over the mini-matrix we created with our bounderies. For each cell, if it not our given cell we increment the cells counter and if it is equal to `1`, we increment the ones counter.

At the end, if the ones counter is smaller than the cells counter, we return true since our cell is not surrounded by `1`s.

### EDIT

The example above returns true if not all of the surrounding cells contain `1`.
But it is possible to change the return value to match different cases:

- If you want to return `true` only when there are 0 cells with `1`, change the return line to the following: `return ones == 0;`
  In this case, the cells counter is unecessary, only the ones counter is needed.
- If you want to return `true` only when all the surrounding cells contain `1`, change to the following: `return ones == cells;`

You can basically change the return value to whatever situation you need, it's very flexible.

Comment: The example returns false only when all the surrounding cells contain '1'. It can be easily changed to return true instead, but your code seemed to return false in that case so I went with it, even though its weird.

Comment: No my code check each case individually, in each case return false if the value of  the surrounded cells in that case equal to 1 ( at least one cell), so u need to modify ur answer.. I need to test it... could u please ?

Comment: Ah! oops, I confused OR and AND. I edited the answer to fit your request. It is a simple change to the return value of the method.

Answer (score 4):

As always, the first rule when programming is: *break down the problem into smaller bits*.

I'll be using *C#7* features just for the fun of it. If you are not using *C#7*, consider translating it to previous versions as an excercise.

Ok, first step. You need neigbouring cells? Allright, lets get all possible neighbouring cells, not caring about wether they exist or not. We'll take care of that later; remember, one small problem at a time.

```
private static IEnumerable<(int Row, int Column)> GetAllNeighbouringCoordinates(int row, int column)
{
    yield return (row - 1, column - 1);
    yield return (row - 1, column);
    yield return (row - 1, column + 1);
    yield return (row, column + 1);
    yield return (row + 1, column + 1);
    yield return (row + 1, column);
    yield return (row + 1, column - 1);
    yield return (row, column - 1);
}
```

Ok, now we have a method that will give us all possible 8 neighbours. The order in which I'm returning them is clockwise, starting at the top left neighbour. Order is unimportant in this case, so consider it an implementation detail.

Now, we need someway to check if any given cell is valid. Ok, that seems easy too:

```
private static bool IsValidCoordinate((int Row, int Column) coord, int rowCount, int columnCount)
{
    Debug.Assert(rowCount >= 0);
    Debug.Assert(columnCount >= 0);

    if (0 > coord.Row || coord.Row >= rowCount ||
        0 > coord.Column || coord.Column >= columnCount)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Ok, that was pretty simply too. See how hard it is to introduce a bug in simple methods?

Also, notice the assertions at the start of the method. This method is not supposed to work with nonsensical values of `rowCount` and `columnCount` so I *enforce* that in code. Because the method is a private helper method, I can simply assert and not throw an exception. If an assertion fails in testing, I know I have a bug in my code.

Now, we just have to glue both things together. Lets build a method that returns the value of all neighbouring cells. We'll use some *LINQ* to remove the unsightly loops:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetNeighbouringCells<T>((int Row, int Column) coord, T[,] cells)
{
    if (cells == null)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    if (!IsValidCoordinate(coord, cells.GetLength(0), cells.GetLength(1)))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    return GetAllNeighbouringCoordinates(coord.Row, coord.Column)
        .Where(c => IsValidCoordinate(c, cells.GetLength(0), cells.GetLength(1)))
        .Select(c => cells[c.Row, c.Column]);
}
```

And there you go, now you have a simple method that will return every neighbouring value of any given cell.

Now, you need all cells where at least one neighbouring cell is zero? Easy peasy:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int Row, int Column)> CellsWithAtLeastOneNeighbourEqualTo<T>(
    this T[,] cells, T value)
{
    for (var row = 0; row < cells.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (var column = 0; column < cells.GetLength(1); column++)
        {
            if (GetNeighbouringCells((row, column), cells).Any(c => c.Equals(value)))
            {
                yield return (row, column);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now if you take it for a small ride:

```
var cells = new[,] { { 0, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 } };
var n = cells.CellsWithAtLeastOneNeighbourEqualTo(0).ToList();
```

You will get the expected results:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a simple game of life program. You should not check everything invidually but use for example a function to check if given a cell's x and y coordinates exist in the table.

Pseudocode:

```
for each cell in celltable
    for each cell surrounding
        if cell index is valid && alive
            alive = alive + 1;
        endif
    endfor
    if alive is valid
       add cell to retList
    alive = 0;
endfor
```

No-one wants to debug huge if-else systems.

Comment: This is very simple program to code with any common programming language. I would rather for you to do the work. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not good in performance, but may solve your problem.

PS. please notice that I renamed your `colIndex` and `rowIndex` to `x` and `y`.

```
static bool TestZero(int[,] array, int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            if (array[x - 1, y - 1] == 1) return false;
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            if (array[x, y - 1] == 1) return false;
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            if (array[x + 1, y - 1] == 1) return false;
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            if (array[x - 1, y] == 1) return false;
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            if (array[x, y] == 1) return false;
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            if (array[x + 1, y] == 1) return false;
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            if (array[x - 1, y + 1] == 1) return false;
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            if (array[x, y + 1] == 1) return false;
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            if (array[x + 1, y + 1] == 1) return false;
        }
        catch { }
        return true;
    }
```

I test with your original case (the first image in your post), use the following code.

```
private static int[,] array = { { 0, 0, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, { 0, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 0, 1, 0 } };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= array.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(TestZero(array, i, j) + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

And the result is

```
True False False False
False False False False
False False False False
False False False False
```

I'm going to test more cases, but at last your can take a try now.

Comment: BTW, my code only answer the "check the cells which surround a specific cell", if you're doing for a game of live (or something similar), you need to do the other stuff by yourself.

Comment: @Kushina, I've tried about 10 cases in different array size (such 4x6) and all passed so far. Leave a comment and tag me if you get any problem. As for the "UGLY", if you don't care the running performance, you may ignore it.

Comment: This is simply horrible, horrible, horrible. Ugh! I'd downvote it 10 times if possible. Using exceptions as a normal control flow mechanism is about as bad as it can get. How this can be the accepted answer is beyond me.

Comment: @InBetween, Yeah, I totally agree. But my original idea is "avoid the complex boundary problem" for OP to easily to debug :P

Comment: @Kushina Just because this code returns the correct values doesn't mean its the right way to do it. This solution is, simply put, a walking coding horror. You should *never, never, never, use exeptions as a control flow mechanism*. Exceptions are *extremely expensive*, if this code has to run in any remotely performant way, you are in for a nasty surprise.

Comment: @Kushina Also, the number of lines has very little to do with the quality of code. The code must be *understandable* and *easy to mantain*. There are one liners that are absolute nightmares whereas equivalent code 10 lines longer are easier to deal with on all aspects.